# Can the English suffix "-zilla" be translated back into Japanese?

Tags: translation, loanwords

Can the English suffix [-zilla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-zilla), a backformation from "Godzilla" describing something as large and/or destructive, be translated into Japanese and easily understood, and how would it be translated? As "ジラ"?

Doing a search of weblio for [zilla](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/zilla) or [ジラ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A9) didn't come up with anything.

Comment: "'Zilla' is an English suffix."て、それはないやろ～。既成事実みたいに言われても、めっさ抵抗あるわ。The very word that we should base this discussion on needs to be 「ゴジラ」, not "Godzilla" or "God + zilla".

Comment: Just came across a Japanese restaurant in Sydney calling itself "Sushizilla" with a katakana name of スシジラ. http://sushizilla.com.au/main.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I remember that this "-zilla" caught on for some reason among English-speaking people, and appeared in several software names such as Mozilla, Bugzilla, FileZilla. English Wikipedia even has a page describing this [suffix -zilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-zilla)!

However, I believe that was an English-only phenomenon, and Japanese people don't regard ジラ as a suffix. FWIW, this "-zilla" originally came from "whale", because [ゴジラ was named after ゴリラ (gorilla) + クジラ (whale)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B4%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A9_(%E6%9E%B6%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%AE%E6%80%AA%E7%8D%A3)#.E8.A3.BD.E4.BD.9C.E7.B5.8C.E7.B7.AF).

That does not mean Japanese doesn't have a similar suffix. One classic example is [-ゴン, which appeared in the names of many imaginary monsters](http://www.infonet.co.jp/apt/march/syllabus/bookshelf/G/gon.html). 教育ママゴン is a buzzword used in the 1980's and it referred to abnormal mothers who were crazy about education.

Comment: あ、 [momzilla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/momzilla) という単語を発見w